# Injected module is undefined when calling module function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, aurelia, es6-class

I'm trying to make a website where i use Aurelia and Javascript and ES6.

I have a simple class (Status) that needs to get some data on a interval from a server.

**Update**
I have added CalcData to the injector as sugessted by Fabio Luz, but i still get the same error. Good call btw ;).

The class looks like this:

```
import {inject} from "aurelia-framework"; // for the inject decorator
import { StatusData } from "./statusData"; // MovieData, the module that will be injected
import { CalcData } from "./Calc"

@inject(StatusData, CalcData) // Inject decorator injects MovieData
 export class Status {

    constructor(StatusData, CalcData) {
        this.statusData2 = StatusData;
        this.CalcData = CalcData;
    }
    activate() {
        setInterval(this.updateCalc, 3000);
    }

    updateCalc() {
        this.CalcData.hello()
            .then(statusData => this.statusData2 = statusData);
    }

    updateStatus() {
        return statusData2.getX()
            .then(statusData => this.statusData2 = statusData);
    }

    update() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The `updateCalc` function is called but when this happens the browser says it that CalcData is undefined.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hello' of undefined
    at updateCalc (status.js:17)
updateCalc @ status.js:17
status.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hello' of undefined
    at updateCalc (status.js:17)
updateCalc @ status.js:17
```

The CalcData class looks like this:

```
import { inject } from "aurelia-framework"; // for the inject decorator
import { HttpClient } from "aurelia-http-client"; // for the http client that will be injected
    let baseUrl = "/movies.json";

    @inject(HttpClient)
    export class CalcData {

    constructor(httpClient) {
        this.http = httpClient;
    }

    hello() {
        return this.http.get(baseUrl)
            .then(response => {
                return response.content;
            });
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find the problem, i have looked around but can't find a solution. I must say that i'm new to  Aurelia.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: How do you instanciate `Status` ? And how do you call `updateCalc` ?

Comment: You're injecting 1 object `@inject(StatusData)`, but your constructor is expecting 2 objects `constructor(StatusData, CalcData)`. The second object will always be undefined

Comment: Thanks for the replys, i have added CalcData to the injector but im still getting the same error.

Comment: How do you call `updateCall()` ?

Comment: In the activate function of the status class with a inteval.  activate() {
        setInterval(this.updateCalc, 3000);
    }

Comment: I it possible to call a class function in a setInterval?

Comment: Seems like i had to bind "this" to pass the object reference. When calling this in hello it how read gets the right object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is down to capitalization, most likely.

Let's look at the beginning of your code:

```
import {inject} from "aurelia-framework"; // for the inject decorator
import { StatusData } from "./statusData"; // MovieData, the module that will be injected
import { CalcData } from "./Calc"

@inject(StatusData, CalcData) // Inject decorator injects MovieData
 export class Status {

    constructor(StatusData, CalcData) {
        this.statusData2 = StatusData;
        this.CalcData = CalcData;
    }
```

Notice that your constructor is taking parameters whose names *exactly* match the names of the classes you want to inject. This is causing confusion for the runtime, as you are likely ending up setting `this.Calcdata` to the class `CalcData` (and the same for `StatusData`). The class does not have a function called `hello()`, only *instances* of the class have that function. If you change the parameter names to not exactly match, your issues should go away.

```
@inject(StatusData, CalcData) // Inject decorator injects MovieData
 export class Status {

    constructor(statusData, calcData) {
        this.statusData = statusData;
        this.calcData = calcData;
    }
```

I've also lower-cased the property names to match JavaScript naming conventions.

Comment: Not the solution to my problem but nice clean up.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like i had to bind "this" to pass the object reference. When calling this in hello it how read gets the right object.

E.g.

```
import {inject} from "aurelia-framework"; 
import {StatusService} from "./statusService"

@inject(StatusService)
export class Status{
      message = 'unknown yet';
      statusService: StatusService;

      constructor(statusService){
            this.statusService = statusService;
      }

      activate(){
          setInterval(this.updateStatus.bind(this), 3000);
      }

       updateStatus = function () {
         this.message =  this.statusService.getX();
      }
}
```

Comment: While this syntax works, it'd probably be more readable to use `setInterval( () => this.message = this.statusService.getX() );`

Comment: Thanks for the comment!